# Strongly typed enum in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, enums

VS doesn't let me compile the code:

```
enum class Traffic_light{ green, yellow, red };
Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
        case Traffic_light::green:  return t = Traffic_light::yellow;
        case Traffic_light::yellow: return t = Traffic_light::red;
        case Traffic_light::red:    return t = Traffic_light::green;
    }
}
```

The example came from the Bjarne Stroustrup's book. I think it might be a problem with C++11 support, but... really? VS 2013 doesn't implement it yet? I've read here, that he does: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#stronglytyped)

Is there something I should or shouldn't do?

Compiller errors:

Error   4   error C2051: case expression not constant

Error   8   error C2051: case expression not constant

Error   12  error C2051: case expression not constant

Error   3   error C2065: 'green' : undeclared identifier

Error   13  error C2065: 'green' : undeclared identifier

Error   9   error C2065: 'red' : undeclared identifier

Error   11  error C2065: 'red' : undeclared identifier

Error   5   error C2065: 'yellow' : undeclared identifier

Error   7   error C2065: 'yellow' : undeclared identifier

Error   1   error C2601: 'operator ++' : local function definitions are illegal

Error   2   error C2653: 'Traffic_light' : is not a class or namespace name

Error   6   error C2653: 'Traffic_light' : is not a class or namespace name

Error   10  error C2653: 'Traffic_light' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: You have a typo: `greem` should be `green`. Fix that and see if it compiles.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I edited my question (add compiler errors).

Comment: I would use a named function rather than an operator here.

Comment: I am trying hard to understand how it is a "Visual Studio" problem. YOu have a problem with your language syntax, not visual studio. Don't blame such a nice tool for something silly.

Comment: @hagubear: it compiles fine with [g++ -std=c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ab28cc007c89f5), so it does seem to be a Visual Studio problem.

Comment: @hagubear : If this is a compiler bug, then information about the toolchain being used isn't irrelevant, it's critical.

Comment: its working fine with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The error "Error 1 error C2601: 'operator ++' : local function definitions are illegal" makes me think that somewhere above that snippet you have a curly brace open so that all this code is actually inside a function definition. Then it's agrammatical altogether.

Comment: There's a [C++11 compatibility table for different versions of Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) which seems to suggest that strongly typed enums should work in VS 2013.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes, it's inside the main() function... Oh my. That  was the problem. I put the definition of Traffic_light before main() and operator++ after it and it is work now. I'm an idiot, sorry guys.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes, this question really has been asked before. Look at that other question. Someone else there asked why it didn't work when `operator++` was defined inside `main`, coming from the same example from the same book.

Comment: @hvd omg. Ok. I deleted my comment. Btw, I didn't see that a link to the older question appeared on top of the page, out of sight when one reads the "marked as duplicate" message (at least on my laptop screen).